# Google Sign in not working in my app

Tags: android, google-signin

Google sign in not working im my android app.

this is my code(from https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in):

```
 public class Login extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, View.OnClickListener {
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 007;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);


        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build();

        SignInButton signInButton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
        signInButton.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_STANDARD);
        signInButton.setScopes(gso.getScopeArray());
        findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(this);


    }


    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.sign_in_button:
                signIn();
                break;
            // ...
        }

    }
    private void signIn() {
        Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            handleSignInResult(result);
        }
    }
    private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
        Log.d(TAG, "handleSignInResult:" + result.isSuccess());
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
            GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
            //mStatusTextView.setText(getString(R.string.signed_in_fmt, acct.getDisplayName()));
            //updateUI(true);
            assert acct != null;
            Toast.makeText(Login.this, acct.getDisplayName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            // Signed out, show unauthenticated UI.
            //updateUI(false);
        }
    }
}
```

i checked in logcat there is no any error..but when i click on google sign in button it shows nothing and app closes automatically

Comment: If app crashed then there should be something in error log. Also check your API key using SHA.

Comment: No the app did not crash,no any error in logcat .app just closes when clicked on button

Comment: Did u check API key ? Also in log it will say something like unauthorized or anything else.

Comment: FirebaseApp initialization successful     its showing this bro..